# Parametrize an intersection of a plane and an elliptic paraboloid

Tags: multivariable-calculus, conic-sections, parametrization

I'm supposed to parametrize the intersection of the plane that has the equation $z = 5x + 3y$ and the 'elliptic paraboloid' with the equation $z = 3x^2+2xy+3y^2$

These two equations can also be written in terms of $u$ and $v$, the plane then has equation $z = 4u + v$ and the paraboloid has $z= 2u^2 + v^2$

How can I go about parametrising these in either domain?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The intersection satisfies

$$ 4u + v = 2u^2 + v^2 \implies 2u^2 - 4u + v^2 - v = 0. $$

Completing the square, we have

$$ 2u^2 - 4u + v^2 - v = 2(u - 1)^2 - 2 + \left( v - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 - \frac{1}{4} = 0 $$

which implies that

$$ 2(u-1)^2 + \left( v - \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 = \frac{9}{4}. $$

This is the equation of an ellipse in the $u$-$v$ plane. Manipulating the equality algebraically, we obtain

$$ \left( \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}(u-1) \right)^2 + \left( \frac{2v - 1}{3} \right)^2 = 1 $$

and so this can be parametrized by letting

$$ \frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}(u - 1) = \cos(\theta), \,\,\, \frac{2v - 1}{3} = \sin(\theta) $$

or, more explicitly,

$$ u = 1 + \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\cos(\theta), \,\,\, v = \frac{3 \sin(\theta) + 1}{2} $$

for $\theta \in [0,2\pi]$.

Comment: That is ingenious, thanks a heap mate! :)